# UV restrictions

Tags: texturing, uv

When you unwrap the mesh, how to restrict some particular faces to apply the texture?

So, some faces will have the texture, some won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make two similar materials, one with texture, the other without, then assign some faces to the first, the other to the the second. All with the same complete UV map. You can also select some faces and UV unwrap only those, then create a new UV map, invert the selection and UV unwrap the rest of the mesh to the new UV map, but I think it's not useful in your case.